# How do I create a Strategy that generates a value in a given range in proptest?

Tags: rust, property-based-testing, proptest

I want to create a `Strategy` that generates `u32` values less than `1000000` efficiently and uniformly.  The only two ways that I know to do this are to use `any::<u32>()` and then do one of the following:

- use `prop_filter` to filter out values greater than or equal to `1000000`
- use `prop_map` to convert the values greater than or equal to `1000000` to values less than `1000000` using the modulus operator (i.e. `.prop_map(|x|x % 1000000)`).  However, this would not provide a uniform sample, and it seems a bit clunky.

Is there any better way to do this, perhaps by using `proptest::prelude::Rng::gen_range()` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `Range`, as their [tutorial states](https://altsysrq.github.io/proptest-book/proptest/tutorial/strategy-basics.html):

> `0..100i32` is a strategy to generate i32s between 0, inclusive, and 100, exclusive

so the strategy for numbers up to `1_000_000` is `0u32..1_000_000`